# Как создать многоуровневый map?

Tags: массивы, kotlin, list, map

Как создать многоуровневый map?
Например, в Python он выглядит таким образом:

```py
vegetables = {}
vegetables.update({veg: {"color": color, "weight": weight}})
```

В итоге `vegetables` получится в такой форме:

```py
vegetables = {apple: {"color": "red", "weight": "0.1 kg"}}
```

Как наполнить такой же `vegetables` в Kotlin?
Объявляю `vegetables`:

```kotlin
var vegetables = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
```

Таким образом не получается:

```kotlin
vegetables[apple]["color"] = "red"
vegetables[apple]["weight"] = "0.1 kg"
```

Так тоже не получается:

```kotlin
vegetables[apple] = ("color" to "red", "weight" to "0.1 kg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Более по Котлин-овски будет вот так

```
data class Vegetable(val color: String, val weight: String)

val vegetables = mutableMapOf <String, Vegetable>()
vegetables["apple"] = Vegetable("red", "0.1 kg")
// либо
val vegetables = ("apple" to Vegetable("red", "0.1 kg"))
```